# laravel relation returning null

Tags: php, laravel

The following keeps bothering me.

**UPDATE**

I, firstly, posted a code which was not meant to post. I updated the code. Please take a look.

A table called **plates**

```
 $table->increments('id');
 $table->integer('equipment_status_code_id')->unsigned();
 $table->foreign('equipment_status_code_id')->references('id')->on('equipment_status_codes')->onDelete('cascade')->onUpdate('cascade');
```

And model **plates**

```
public function equipmentStatusCode()
{
   return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\EquipmentStatusCode');
}
```

and **EquipmentStatusCode**

```
   public function plate()
    {
         return $this->hasOne('App\Models\Plate');
    }
```

In route I do this

```
   $data = Plate::find(1);
   $att = $data->equipmentStatusCode;

   dd($att);
```

And works just fine.

**But** the other way around won't work and returns **null**

```
$data = EquipmentStatusCode::find(1);
$att = $data->plate;

dd($att);
```

Someone tells me what's going on?

Answer (score 1):

The model with the `BelongsTo` relation should have the [foreign key in its table](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#one-to-one). You have it the other way around. So just swap the relations.

Plate Model:

```
public function equipmentStatusCode()
{
   return $this->hasOne('App\Models\EquipmentStatusCode');
}
```

EquipmentStatusCode Model:

```
public function plate()
{
   return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Plate');
}
```